Can files be added to a read only directory by using overlayfs?
I want to add some files to a read-only directory or at least simulate so. In the following example from this page:
cd /tmp
mkdir lower upper workdir overlay

sudo mount -t overlay -o \
  lowerdir=/tmp/lower,\
  upperdir=/tmp/upper,\
  workdir=/tmp/workdir \
  none /tmp/overlay

I guess the read-only directory would be /tmp/lower and the files I want to add would be copied to /tmp/upper. But how to make the system read /tmp/overlay instead of /tmp/lower?. Does bindfs have anything to do here?
